# Firefox support of webkit vendor prefixes

Tags: css, firefox, webkit

I've got this SCSS code:

```
.gradient-text {
    color: mix(#cea427, #fbe758); // Fallback to average of 2 colors
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #cea427, #fbe758);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4bdLxkLf/)

At first I just wanted to make this code work in webkit-based browsers and then add different approach for firefox, but I've found out that at least latest nightly firefox runs this code too, even if it's vendor-prefixed for webkit.

I won't worry if there was only one property, which can be either supported by firefox or not. But having 2 properties makes me nervous about the situation where only one of them is working. For example, supported `-webkit-linear-gradient` and unsupported `-webkit-background-clip` will work vastly different from my expectations. So, is there any way I can check browser support for multiple CSS rules and gracefylly switch to fallback if at least one of them is missing?

And also, is there any list of foreign vendor prefixes support (like `-webkit-` prefix support in FF)?

Comment: "is there any list of foreign vendor prefixes support" -webkit- is the only prefix you need to worry about. Hooray for a WebKit monoculture.

Comment: Maybe relevant http://caniuse.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these sort of situations, I always find it very helpful to check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). In this case, you can check the articles for [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient), [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) and [`-webkit-text-fill-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color). Near the bottom, there is always a section titled **Browser compatibility**. It lists, in a table, browsers that support the CSS rules and in footnotes goes into specifics. For example, about the `-webkit-text-fill-color`, it says that

> [1] This feature is implemented behind the preference `layout.css.prefixes.webkit`, defaulting to `false`. Since Gecko 49 (Firefox 49.0 / Thunderbird 49.0 / SeaMonkey 2.46) the preference defaults to `true`.

This should answer your question on why the `-webkit-` prefixed version is supported, and since when. Also note that at the top, the article mentions

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

So: ye be warned.

In this particular case, you might be able to get away with what you want to do, at least in Firefox and Chrome. Other browsers... that's trickier.

---

Your other question is if you can gracefully switch to a fallback when a rule is not supported. Unfortunately, this is not possible in pure CSS. It is possible to write [rules that specifically target Chrome](//stackoverflow.com/q/9328832/962603) or [Firefox](//stackoverflow.com/q/952861/962603) though, but I would advise against using those. You could maybe check for support using JavaScript, but that is something I wholeheartedly advise against.

---

Finally, "is there any list of foreign vendor prefixes support (like `-webkit-` prefix support in FF)?" [Sort of](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/09/firefox-49-fixes-sites-designed-with-webkit-in-mind-and-more/). Again, MDN is usually very complete and up-to-date. Hope that helps.

Comment: The same is true of IE11 and Microsoft Edge. I'm still bitter that things had to come to this, but it is what it is.